# Find last row excluding headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have several trackers which are then copied and pasted into a Masterfile.

Can you please help? Thanks!

Some of these trackers are empty, and when I copy them into the masterfile with the last row function, it copies the headers.

For example

```
Project Name | Project Owner
_empty_          _empty_

__Tracker 2__
Project Name | Project Owner
_HOUSING_          _JHON_

__Masterfile__
Project Name | Project Owner
Project Name | Project Owner   --> from tracker 1 (it's empty, it copies headers)
_HOUSING_          _JHON_  --> from tracker 2, not empty it copies values
```

Data starts at A9 of tab "Scheme Overview" and this is my code:

```vb
lastrow = wb.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row                    ' Determine last row in Tracker file, column D (scheme name)

Starplan.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Activate
star_row = Starplan.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row             ' Determine last row +1 in Master Tracker


Dim range1 As Range
Set range1 = wb.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Range("$A$9:$U" & lastrow)                                     ' Select data in individual file
range1.Copy                                                                  

Starplan.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Cells(star_row, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats   ' Paste into column A of Master Tracker
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I expect the output to be

```
__Masterfile__
Project Name | Project Owner   
_HOUSING_          _JHON_  --> values only from trackers which are not empty
```

Comment: Note that `.Offset(0, 0)` is completely useless and should be removed. Just check if the `lastrow` is row number `1` (which is the header) if it is row 1 then don't copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the `lastrow` is row number `1` (which is the header) if it is row 1 then don't copy:

```
If lastrow > 1 Then
    'copy
Else
   MsgBox "There is nothing to copy besides the header."
End If
```

Comment: @Mikku Well, If the header is in row 3 then of course you need to replace `1` with `3` like `If lastrow > 3 Then`

Answer (score 0):

**Put this condition:**

```
If range1.Rows.Count > 1 Then

range1.Copy

Starplan.Sheets("Scheme Overview").Cells(star_row, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats   ' Paste into column A of Master Tracker

End If
```

Counting the number of Rows and if they are greater than 1, then copy them